# Android Constraint layout within the scrollview marginTop won't effect

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am having trouble in setting up the top margin for the ImageView within the constraint layout. Here is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.roadrez.AuthActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_auth">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/mt_layout_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/mt_layout_padding"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/login_logo"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="96dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/logo"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

top_to_top_of constraint is missing thats why margin/padding is not set.

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/login_logo"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
```